# Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone returns UTC and not Europe/London

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output the user's timezone using

```js
 console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

but this is returning UTC and not Europe/London like I want / was expecting. Any idea as to why?

Comment: This outputs "Europe/Rome" for me, which is correct. And if I change my system timezone to UK it then outputs "Europe/London".  So I can't reproduce the problem and it may be specific to your device.

Comment: I am aware of what this outputs to others, but for some reason, it displays UTC for me,  I have no clue as to why

Comment: Do you have any info about the device or operating system?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 64-bit, GNOME Version 3.36.8

Comment: This problem has been reported since 2017 and is apparently related to customized settings in the OS and/or the browser.  So this is an issue you will need to troubleshoot.  Check if the problem affects both Chrome and Firefox, if disabling OS automatic time zone has any effect, etc.

Comment: If I type that directly into the console of chromium, I get Europe/London, which is correct, but when I console.log() it in my terminal I get UTC